# Как запретить масштабирование графика TeeChart ниже определённой границы?

Tags: delphi, teechart

Как убрать возможность масштабирования графика TeeChart ниже определённой границы, например, когда цена деления меньше заданной константы. Может есть какой-то стандартный флажок, проперти для этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно включить историю зума `Zoom.History`, и при нежелательном изменении возвращать последние пределы.

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1Zoom(Sender: TObject);
var
  zs: TZoomSnapshot;
begin
   if Chart1.BottomAxis.Maximum - Chart1.BottomAxis.Minimum < 1 then
     if Chart1.Zoom.AxesHistory.Count = 0 then
       Chart1.BottomAxis.SetMinMax(0, 1)
     else begin
       zs := Chart1.Zoom.AxesHistory.Last;
       Chart1.BottomAxis.SetMinMax(zs.AxesMinMax[6], zs.AxesMinMax[7]);
           // они бы это ещё документировали   ^^^^^^
     end;
end;
```

P.S. UnZoom (увеличение масштаба), правда, на этом примере нехорошо работает, шагами, а не сразу до максимума, но это уже можно решить.

Comment: Спасибо! А для чего служит TZoomSnapshot ? Гугл молчит, 16 результатов всего.  И AxesHistory.  И почему именно AxesMinMax[6] и AxesMinMax[7]? Можно прокоментировать в общем, что происходит, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Если включена история зумов, то после выполнения каждого масштабирования запоминаются параметры мин-макс по осям - это и есть  TZoomSnapshot  - "снимок" параметров. AxesHistory - список этих снимков. Для нижней оси используются указанные элементы массива, какие за другие оси отвечают - надо методом тыка искать или смотреть в исходниках, если они у кого-то есть. TZoomSnapshot в хелпе TeeChart есть, но топик пустой. AxesMinMax - вообще в хелпе нет.

Comment: Хм. Через Minimum, AutomaticMinimus и Increment это не решается?

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov Наверное, решается, тем более что зум не делает ничего особого, кроме задания начала и конца осей - того же SetMinMax.

Comment: @MBo Тогда проще идти через них, тем более, что подобный подход они озвучивали на семинарах

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov Можно. Ничем особо не проще - ведь в обоих случаях проверяется некий допуск, и делается SetMinMax, но имеется элемент дополнительного контроля, если в этом есть потребность. А нет потребности - так пусть последний нормальный режим используется.

Comment: @MBo ЕМНИП, проще тем, что вообще не надо писать обработчик.

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov Увы, Increment относится лишь к меткам - т.е. метки останутся редкими, а масштаб можно ещё увеличивать. Или Вы имеете в виду какой-то ещё приём?